# Trying to find the title of two different books. Both fantasy

Tags: story-identification

The first one is about a boy who got left a key by a neighbour who dies and has instructions to go through his back gate (maybe) at a certain time. it takes him to another world where he learns magic and gains the ability to create worlds.
Think it had a couple of books in a series. one of them had it where he had to move the people from this planet to earth.

Second one is also in a series. I only got to read the second one though.
A guy somehow ended up in a different realm where his computer coding skills turned out to be a new way to cast magic but he got kidnapped and his friends from earth had to be called in to travel to the new realm to help find him.

Any help identifying these is much appreciated.

Comment: If you have two books, please [ask](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) two different questions.

Comment: lso, welcome to [scif.se]. You might want to take the [tour].

Comment: First one might be [Songs of Earth and Power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/75953/38235), which I hunted once upon a time.  Split up your questions and I'll be happy to answer with details.

Answer (score 2):

I think I can answer the second question - sounds like it might be the second book in the Wizadry series by Rick Cook. The title is The Wizadry Compiled - in the book the hero - Wiz Zumwalt - collects several programmers from earth to help hime improve his 'magic compiler' that is introduced in the first book 'Wizards Bane'. I can't remember exactly but I believe he is kidnapped for part of the book leaving his friends to work on the compiler in his absence.

Further info can be found on goodreads - http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/981834.The_Wizardry_Compiled

Also there is a wiki on the series at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Cook